# setState() not working for a specific component in my development environment

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a simple setState() call:

`this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible});`

However, it seems to do nothing. All of my other stateful components update just fine, but after this setState call it never even reaches the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method. It also won't reach a callback if I pass one to the set state method. I'm confident it isn't a binding issue since it's able to access the component's initial state the line right before this call.

Ideally, when that line runs, it will open a react bootstrap modal with a short form. I'm confident setState() isn't executing properly anywhere in this component because if I cheat and set the state `visible: true` in the constructor so the modal is visible on page load, typing into the input fields also isn't updating the component state.

To top it all off, I only see this problem with this specific component in my local development environment. It works just fine in production and in the local development environments of the other engineers on my team.

Any ideas on how to approach debugging this?

Comment: Could be that something is wrong with your node_modules/versioning. Try removing node_modules and reinstalling with `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you! I'd tried recompiling the js from scratch but hadn't tried reinstalling all the modules. That fixed it.